# How can shared_ptr disrupt alignment

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, shared-ptr, directxmath

I'm reading docs on DirectXMath, and stumbled upon next passage:

> As an alternative to enforcing alignment in your C++ class directly by
>   overloading new/delete, you can use the *pImpl idiom.* If you ensure
>   your Impl class is aligned via __aligned_malloc internally, you can
>   then freely use aligned types within the internal implementation. This
>   is a good option when the 'public' class is a Windows Runtime ref
>   class or intended for use with std::shared_ptr<>, which can otherwise
>   disrupt careful alignment.

I don't understand how shared_ptr can do any change in alignment strategy, it only have a pointer, it doesn't allocate an object.

Comment: I agree. It seems to me that the docs are outdated. in c++11 you can specify the alignment of your data type via attributes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right, `std::shared_ptr` doesn't affect alignment. It just takes in a pointer to an already allocated object, so if that allocation resulted in a misaligned object, the problem isn't with `std::shared_ptr`, it's with that allocation.

But `std::shared_ptr` is often used with `std::make_shared`. `std::make_shared<T>` performs a single allocation to reserve memory both for the `std::shared_ptr` control structure and the `T` instance. This allocation isn't done using any class-specific `operator new` (and shouldn't be). If the class-specific `operator new` sets up stricter alignment than what the default allocator does, then it's easy to see how this can fail when the default allocator gets used.

Comment: Also even if the ``operator new`` is using 16-byte alignment (such as with x64 native), the standard doesn't require the extra space allocated with ``std::make_shared`` respects the alignment of the class itself.

Comment: Took me a thousand hours of debugging to finally find the culprit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is why sometimes intrusive ref-count is preferred over std::shared_ptr, you can explicitly declare the alignment requirement for your class.

Also, remember to declare the destructor as private to forbid (de)allocation on stack.