What memory alignment boundary is used for the memory returned by std::make_shared<uchar>?
I need to allocate a buffer that is at aligned to a 32 bit boundary (4 bytes).
Will std::make_shared do that?   I think it is likely but don't know if it can be guaranteed... as the basic alignment requirement for uchar is one byte.

std::make_shared<uchar> will not create a buffer anyway, just a shared_ptr on a single uchar. Maybe you want to create an aligned unsigned char array then pass it to the third constructor there? Does your requirement be that you'll store objects all suitably aligned in the buffer?

forget the 2nd question as the size (sizeof) of your object must be a multiple of its alignment.

The alignment is guaranteed to be at least whatever alignof(uchar) is, whatever that may be.

Yes you're right I want to create an array of uchar[] not a single uchar

So my guess would be to allocate your buffer with std::aligned_alloc and guive it to std::shared_ptr constructor along with a deleter. Then you can use new-placement to construct your objects inside the buffer (but you'll have to destroy then manually). They are some exception if your objects are implicit-lifetime, trivially-destructible,... or other some nice properties...

note also that, by default the alignment should be STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT which might be enough for your need

@Oersted make_shared creates a type-erased struct the holds both your object and the control block, it is not subject to the alignment requirements of new, but as the control block normally needs to be aligned to a pointer and padded to that, the object after it should also be aligned to a pointer alignment .... or at least that's what most implementations do right now, but hypothetically someone could create a control block that causes the object after it to be aligned to 1 byte instead of 8

@AhmedAEK you are confusion me. Are you speaking about the alignment of the address returned by get() on a resource created with make_shared or of the alignment of the shared_ptr itself (which is meaningless IMHO)?

@Oersted the alignment of the pointed-to object you get back from get

@Oersted you can imagine on some very constrained controller defining the type-erased deleters as indicies to some very small table, so the control block could be like 7 bytes, and your object would be placed at the 8th byte, this implementation would still be standard compliant, but if your object must be aligned to 4 bytes then the compiler must add extra padding.

@AhmedAEK as far as I can dive into the standard, it does not seem to clearly states how memory should be allocated. There seems to be only an indirect mention to allocate that may throw std::bad_alloc. So I would still go for the proposal I made in a previous comment, using your answer only if the size is known at compile-time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31229088/21691539

Most implementations of std::make_shared will align a char to a pointer alignment (8 bytes), but it is not guaranteed, And therefore this is not portable.
If you want a portable buffer with a specific alignment then use std::aligned_storage, which must have the correct alignment with make_shared, you can use the overload of make_shared that creates an array of objects if you want to decide the buffer size at runtime, and you want to watch out for the strict aliasing rule when treating it as another type.
As per @TedLyngmo as aligned storage is deprecated in C++23, to make it future-proof you should make your own aligned buffer type
Why is std::aligned_storage to be deprecated in C++23 and what to use instead?

I'd create my own aligned storage since std::aligned_storage is/will be deprecated (since C++23).

std::aligned_storage requires to know the buffer size at compile-time. OP didn't tell if it's the case.

@Oersted you can always create an array of these aligned storages, but a vector of the intended type with a custom allocator would be more suitable.
